# Book about organization who can erase time

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel

Has anyone heard about a book where there’s an organization that can erase people or time streams and one of the guys involved falls in love with someone he’s suppose to erase?

Comment: This is quite a common idea in SF, but as user14111 suggests The End of Eternity by Asimov is a famous novel that fits your description.

Comment: "This is how you lose the time war" would be a recent example. Digging out others would take me more brain power than I have available right now.

Comment: Possibly Kevin O'Donnell jr.'s *War of Omission*. https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1798065.War_Of_Omission

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen - I don't remember any _organized_ erasure in that book; the TSS ("tisser") was used more as a "terroristic" device.

Comment: Are you trying to find a specific book (in which case, please add a few more details of the plot, when it was published/read, etc), or are you looking for suggestions of similar books?

Comment: I agree, it's probably Asimov's TEOE. @user14111, you should add that as an answer.

Comment: It was End of eternity, thank you